# HTTPS:// is not working on Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, magento

My domain is: http://indiasaplings.com/

I ran this command: `sudo certbot --nginx -d indiasaplings.com -d www.indiasaplings.com`

**It produced this output:**

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:

Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
/etc/letsencrypt/live/indiasaplings.com/fullchain.pem
Your key file has been saved at:
/etc/letsencrypt/live/indiasaplings.com/privkey.pem
Your cert will expire on 2019-12-29. To obtain a new or tweaked
version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot again
with the “certonly” option. To non-interactively renew all of
your certificates, run “certbot renew”
```

- CMS: Mazento 2
- Web Server: Nginx
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Hosting: AWS

**Here is my server block:-**

```
server {
   # if ($host = indiasaplings.com) {
    #    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   # } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name indiasaplings.com www.indiasaplings.com;
   # return 301 https://indiasaplings.com$request_uri;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/sm/sm_shopee;
    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 1;
    include /etc/nginx/m2/m231.conf;


}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name indiasaplings.com www.indiasaplings.com;
  # return 301 https://indiasaplings.com$request_uri;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/sm/sm_shopee;
    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 1;
    include /etc/nginx/m2/m231.conf;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/indiasaplings.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/indiasaplings.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    listen              443 ssl default_server;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name         indiasaplings.com www.indiasaplings.com;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/hmtl/sm/sm_shopee;
    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 1;
   include /etc/nginx/m2/m231.conf;

    }
```

I am not able to open my site on HTTPS:// even after installing and configuring Let’s Encrypt. Please guide, Thank you!

Comment: What's the actual error you get when you try to connect to your server with https?

Comment: And please, don't post screenshots of text that you can just copy&paste

Comment: Sorry, from next time i will remember this.

Comment: This site can’t be reached

indiasaplings.com unexpectedly closed the connection.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: Try removing the second serverblock that is missing the SSL certificates.

Comment: This one?  listen 80;
 server_name indiasaplings.com www.indiasaplings.com;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99291/discussion-between-techiebraj-and-gerald-schneider).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two server blocks with both `listen 443` and `server_name indiasaplings.com`. One has the certificate files configured, the second is missing them. Remove the 443 block without certificate files.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now :)